# How to quietly continue processing tasks using Azure durable functions fan-out fan-in pattern with task_any function

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a list of tasks that need completed. As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions-durable/azure.durable_functions.models.durableorchestrationcontext.durableorchestrationcontext?view=azure-python#azure-durable-functions-models-durableorchestrationcontext-durableorchestrationcontext-task-all), the `task_all` method will throw an exception whenever **any** of the tasks fail. According to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/477#issuecomment-1428850454), when one of the tasks fails, the `task_all` function throws an error and **stops waiting for the rest of the tasks to complete**. I want to wait for all the tasks to complete regardless of if any of the tasks fail. I have tried to implement the workaround seen [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/477#issuecomment-1428870997), but it does not work in Python. Does anyone know a way around this issue?

Answer (score -1):

In order to wait for all tasks to complete without any failures, You can make use of **asyncio.gather** method in your azure function code like below:-

**init.py** file:-

```py
import  logging

import  azure.functions  as  func

import  asyncio

  

async  def  task1():

# Do some work here

await  asyncio.sleep(1)

  

async  def  task2():

# Do some work here

await  asyncio.sleep(2)

  

async  def  task3():

# Do some work here

await  asyncio.sleep(3)

  

async  def  main():

tasks = [task1(), task2(), task3()]

try:

await  asyncio.gather(*tasks)

except  Exception  as  e:

logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")

raise  e

  

async  def  main_handler(req: func.HttpRequest, res: func.Out[func.HttpResponse]) -> None:

logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

  

await  main()

  

res.set(func.HttpResponse(

"All tasks completed successfully.",

status_code=200

))
```

***With some sample task in #Do some work:-***

**Updated init.py** file:-

```py
import  logging

import  azure.functions  as  func

import  asyncio

  

async  def  task1():

print("Task 1 started")

await  asyncio.sleep(1)

print("Task 1 completed")

  

async  def  task2():

print("Task 2 started")

await  asyncio.sleep(2)

print("Task 2 completed")

  

async  def  task3():

print("Task 3 started")

await  asyncio.sleep(3)

print("Task 3 completed")

  

async  def  main():

tasks = [task1(), task2(), task3()]

try:

await  asyncio.gather(*tasks)

except  Exception  as  e:

logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")

raise  e

  

async  def  main_handler(req: func.HttpRequest, res: func.Out[func.HttpResponse]) -> None:

logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

  

await  main()

  

res.set(func.HttpResponse(

"All tasks completed successfully.",

status_code=200

))
```

**function.json** file:-

```json
{

"bindings": [

{

"name": "req",

"type": "httpTrigger",

"direction": "in",

"methods": [ "get", "post" ]

},

{

"name": "res",

"type": "http",

"direction": "out"

}

],

"scriptFile": "__init__.py",

"entryPoint": "main_handler"

}
```

**requirements.txt** file:-

```
azure-functions
asyncio
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***With sample task:-***

**Output:-**

[image]

**Browser:-**

[image]